# Solving $2x=\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{1-y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a bit embarrassing, but I can't seem to solve for $x$ in
$$2x=\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{1-y}.$$
Could someone please give me a hand!

Comment: $x\left(2-\frac1{y}\right)=-\frac1{1-y}$. Do you see how to solve now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $\frac xy = x\cdot\frac1y$, so
$$
2x = \frac xy-\frac{1}{1-y}\Leftrightarrow x\cdot\left(2-\frac1y\right) = -\frac1{1-y}\Leftrightarrow x = \frac{y}{(1-y)(1-2y)}.
$$
Here you should be aware that $y\neq 0,y\neq 1$ (as it appears in the original equation). Moreover, $y\neq1/2$ which apper in the final answer does not reduce the space of solutions since the original equation does not have a solution in $x$ if $y=1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

$2x-\frac{x}{y}=\frac{1}{y-1}$

$x(2-\frac{1}{y})=\frac{1}{y-1}$

$x(\frac{2y-1}{y})=\frac{1}{y-1}$

$x=\frac{y}{(y-1)(2y-1)}$